# "mvn clean install" failed in command line, but passed in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

New to java and intellij, pls forgive me if i cannot describe the issue clearly.
Brand new install of intellij, brand new import of the java project.

From beginning, seems the project builds fine in intellij, in the GUI there's that clean/compile/verify/install/... life cycles. I click clean, then install, it triggers the unit test and all passing. Now i go to the project root in the command line, "mvn clean install" also passing.

Now i make a change to a resource file, *.sql which is used for in-memory db setup for unit test. i click clean, then install, still passes successfully.

Now i go to the command line again, "mvn clean install" fails in unit test.

I'm so confused now, either way i'm doing the "clean", what's the cause and how should to fix it pls ?

BTW, after working in visual studio for so long, this java and intellij is giving me heart attacks, why the build system in java is so hard and messy ?

Answer (score 1):

Your project is likely configured differently from the maven pom.xml file. When the two aren't configured the same, you'll have problems. I would guess that some dependency is configured correctly in the IntelliJ Project file, but not in the pom.xml. I usually have the reverse problem. I use only the pom.xml to specify dependencies, and rely on the maven plugin to refresh the project (eclipse).

With IntelliJ, it's been a few years, but I remember the same idea. Try deleting the project file, and importing an existing maven pom file. Then modify your dependencies using only the pom.xml and not IntelliJ's project interface. If the pom.xml is correctly defined, the project import will work first try. That heavily depends upon the previous developer working with the project.

Comment: Make sense. The puzzle is, when i opened the project in initellij in the beginning, pretty sure i browsed and opened the exact same existing pom.xml. After that, i never edited the pom.xml.

Comment: Did you "open the project", or did you "Import the pom"?

Comment: Yes i mean "Import Project" when starting intellij

Comment: Import Project will let you choose a pom file

Comment: btw Happy Thanksgiving Kieveli !

Answer (score 1):

Maven is actually a very powerful (if not quirky at times) build tool, and the differences between execution on command line or "inside" IntelliJ are usually simple to explain.

Please check:

- you are running the same version of maven (check command line with -version, compare to intellij setup in settings
- you are using the same local `.m2` folder (local repo) for maven vs intellij
- you are not running with any "Profiles" in intellij (check that none are ticked).
- you are not skipping any tests because they end with "IT" (meaning Integration Test)

These are the common reasons for differences.

If you post a log of your failing build we might be able to help more.

Comment: sorry for replying late, mvn is 3.6.2 in command line, it's 3.6.1 in intellij, minor difference, but i don't understand why different version, brand new mac, brand new install of maven and intellij

Comment: Intellij uses /home/user/.m2, there's a settings.xml in this folder. No any other .m2 folder i created in this MAC. For command line, i don't know if it's using the same .m2, but as i mentioned, i only created this only one .m2.

Answer (score 0):

ok, my friend found the issue, in Maven settings in intellij, there's a "Runner" page, there's a "Skip test" there. In my case it's checked, so the run in intellij skipped unit test (which should fail) and did all other stuff, made it looks like it's passing.
Still several puzzles to me, but this "Runner" -> "Skip test" fixed the issue.
Pretty upset with intellij.